# How can I SELECT+INSERT in the same mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a php script that process keywords from a mysql table "keywords" (columns: id - keyword) and then it saves data into another table "data" (column: id[foreign key keywords.id] - dataname - datavalue).

My problem is that when the script is ready to save the data I only have the keyword and not the id.

So is there a way I can get the keyword id and save the data in one mysql query? (i mean without having to do something like SELECT id from keywords where keyword = keyword, and then run another query for the INSERT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If selecting and modification tables are different - you can use simple nested query:

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `dataname`) VALUES
(
    (SELECT `id` FROM `keywords` WHERE `keyword` = 'keyworrrrrd'),
    'blabla'
)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `dataname`)
SELECT `id`, 'blabla' FROM `keywords` WHERE `keyword` = 'keyworrrrrd'
```

Comment: Thanks i think that will do the job.

Comment: @Frankie: i've written in that way to differ `keyword` as field and specific keyword in table ;-)